# Copies of vectors from list

Tags: r, loops, copy

I have  a list of vectors and want to copy each vetor a certain amount of time. Thus, in the end I want to have list with copied vectors, for example 5 copies.

```
v1=c(1,2,3)
v2=c(4,5,6)
v3=c(7,8,9)

my_list=list(v1,v2,v3)
```

If I am applying rep it works, I got the copies, but I have to do it individually.

```
rep(my_list[1], times=5)
```

If am trying a for loop to do it automatically for each vector from the list, it does not work.

```
  new_list =  for (i in 1:3){

    rep(my_list[i], times=5)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `replicate`

```
 do.call(c, replicate(5, my_list, simplify = FALSE))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can subset your list with repeating indices:

```r
my_list[rep(seq_along(my_list), each = 5)]

#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1 2 3
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 1 2 3
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 1 2 3
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] 1 2 3
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [1] 1 2 3
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> [1] 4 5 6
#> 
#> [[7]]
#> [1] 4 5 6
#> 
#> [[8]]
#> [1] 4 5 6
#> 
#> [[9]]
#> [1] 4 5 6
#> 
#> [[10]]
#> [1] 4 5 6
#> 
#> [[11]]
#> [1] 7 8 9
#> 
#> [[12]]
#> [1] 7 8 9
#> 
#> [[13]]
#> [1] 7 8 9
#> 
#> [[14]]
#> [1] 7 8 9
#> 
#> [[15]]
#> [1] 7 8 9
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>